# How to uninstall Sahi Pro on Windows 7 ?

Tags: windows-7, uninstallation, sahi

I have install Sahi Pro by using "install_sahi_pro_v452_20130205.jar" on Windows 7. I have decided to uninstall it and to install Sahi Pro 5.

I went to Control Panel --> Uninstall a Program to uninstall Sahi Pro 4. But I did not find Sahi Pro on the uninstall program list. How can I uninstall Sahi Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the following steps to uninstall Sahi Pro:

1. Open command prompt --> Navigate to the folder sahi_pro where Sahi Pro has been installed
2. Go to Uninstaller folder (cd Uninstaller)
3. Execute the command below to run uninstaller.jar:

   java -jar uninstaller.jar
4. Click Uninstall button at the pop up

Comment: My installer folser is C:\Users\DELL\sahi_pro. I navigated to C:\Users\DELL\sahi_pro\Uninstaller at command prompt and executed 'java -jar uninstaller.jar' and uninstalled successfully.

Comment: sorry for spelling mistake. It is folder instead of folser at 1st line.